# What does the word 「でやんして」 mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, manga

I also would like to know if it relates to any dialect.

> A: またそんなことでこそこそやってるのか。
> B: なんせ　我々にとっては重大{じゅうだい}問題{もんだい}**でやんして**...

Comment: I think this might be でやんす, the old equivalent to です? I'm not completely sure, which is why I'm commenting, but this is the [weblio entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%84%E3%82%93%E3%81%99). Says it was used in Kansai during the Edo period. I think its only used jokingly in modern japanese.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a dialect, and it is an old one. A quick equivalency would be:

でやんす =　で　ございます

でやんして = で　ございまして

我々にとっては重大問題でやんして = 我々にとっては重大問題でございまして

Here's a good description from the home page of Sano city, Gifu prefecture which digs a bit into the grammar of it. Since it's on the city's site as an introduction of the regional culture, I imagine it is done by proper authority of the field, so I would defer the technical aspects of it to this page.

https://www.city.sano.lg.jp/soshikiichiran/sougou/toshibrandsuishin/gyomuannai/koho/7/2023/21145.html